# Access vba Hyperlink

Tags: vba, ms-access

EDIT: **Solved it by resetting Chrome!**

In a product detail form (wine) I would need a subform with a series of clickable links. I therefore created a table:

```
IDproduct
LinkName 
LinkUrl
```

I need to have a list like:

```
<a href=[LinkUrl]>[LinkName]</a>
```

I tried with an event:

```
Private Sub LinkName_Click()
    If Nz(Me.LinkUrl, "") > "" Then Application.FollowHyperlink Me.LinkUrl
End Sub
```

It shows me a warning about the danger of opening a link, but it doesn't open my browser. Are there other ways?

Comment: What's your LinkUrl format ? Have your checked Application.FollowHyperlink 
 " https: //www.google.com " ? If this works. So maybe your LinkUrl is in bad format.

Comment: Yes: not working ...

Answer (score 0):

Could try Shell method, example from my db:

```
Dim wsShell As Object
Set wsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsShell.Run Chr(34) & Me.tbxLink & Chr(34)
ExitProc:
Set wsShell = Nothing
Exit Sub
ErrProc:
MsgBox "Cannot open document. Contact database administrator. : " & Err.Number
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I restart Chrome ... **and now it works!**